# how do i remove buttons off a message?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

```
button = Button(style = discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji = ":arrow_backward:", custom_id = "button1")
button2 = Button(style = discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji = ":arrow_up_small:", custom_id = "button2")
button3 = Button(style = discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji = ":arrow_forward:", custom_id = "button3")
view = View()
view.add_item(button)
view.add_item(button2)
view.add_item(button3)

async def button_callback(interaction):
    if number != ("⠀⠀1"):
        await message.edit(content="**response 1**")
    else:
        await message.edit(content="**response 2**")

async def button_callback2(interaction):
    if number != ("⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀2"):
        await message.edit(content="**response 1**")
    else:
        await message.edit(content="**response 2**")

async def button_callback3(interaction):
    if number != ("⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀3"):
        await message.edit(content="**response 1**")
    else:
        await message.edit(content= "**response 2**")

button.callback = button_callback
button2.callback = button_callback2
button3.callback = button_callback3

await message.edit(content= f"⠀⠀:watermelon:⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀:watermelon:⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀:watermelon:\n{number}", view=view)
```

In the code it creates and sends a message with buttons on it, once you press the button itll either edit the message to say "response1" or "response2" depending if the button had the 1, 2 ,3 over it (if it didnt have the number over it, it prints "response1" if it did have the number over it, it prints "response2") i would like it so when it edits it to either of the responses it also removes the buttons, as it currently doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Set `view=None` in your `message.edit` function call to remove all of the buttons.